# Full outer join in Scala

Tags: scala

Given a list of lists, where each list has an object that represents the key, I need to write a full outer join that combines all the lists. Each record in the resulting list is the combination of all the fields of all the lists. In case that one key is present in list 1 and not present in list 2, then the fields in list 2 should be null or empty.

One solution I thought of is to embed an in-memory database, create the tables, run a select and get the result. However, I'd like to know if there are any libraries that handle this in a more simpler way. Any ideas?

For example, let's say I have two lists, where the key is the first field in the list:

```
val list1 = List ((1,2), (3,4), (5,6))
val list2 = List ((1,"A"), (7,"B"))
val allLists = List (list1, list2)
```

The full outer joined list would be:

```
val allListsJoined = List ((1,2,"A"), (3,4,None), (5,6,None), (7,None,"B"))
```

**NOTE:** the solution needs to work for N lists

Comment: Your question is not clear enough, at least for me. What is a "field" in a list? How do you "combine" them? Please provide an example

Comment: Added the example

Comment: What have you already try as code?

Comment: You can try transforming list into maps, using `groupBy(_._1)`

Answer (score 2):

```
def fullOuterJoin[K, V1, V2](xs: List[(K, V1)], ys: List[(K, V2)]): List[(K, Option[V1], Option[V2])] = {
  val map1 = xs.toMap
  val map2 = ys.toMap
  val allKeys = map1.keySet ++ map2.keySet
  allKeys.toList.map(k => (k, map1.get(k), map2.get(k)))
}
```

Example usage:

```
val list1 = List ((1,2), (3,4), (5,6))
val list2 = List ((1,"A"), (7,"B"))
println(fullOuterJoin(list1, list2))
```

Which prints:

```
List((1,Some(2),Some(A)), (3,Some(4),None), (5,Some(6),None), (7,None,Some(B)))
```

Edit per suggestion in comments:

If you're interested in joining an arbitrary number of lists and don't care about type info, here's a version that does that:

```
def fullOuterJoin[K](xs: List[List[(K, Any)]]): List[(K, List[Option[Any]])] = {
  val maps = xs.map(_.toMap)
  val allKeys = maps.map(_.keySet).reduce(_ ++ _)
  allKeys.toList.map(k => (k, maps.map(m => m.get(k))))
}

val list1 = List ((1,2), (3,4), (5,6))
val list2 = List ((1,"A"), (7,"B"))
val list3 = List((1, 3.5), (7, 4.0))
val lists = List(list1, list2, list3)
println(fullOuterJoin(lists))
```

which outputs:

```
List((1,List(Some(2), Some(A), Some(3.5))), (3,List(Some(4), None, None)), (5,List(Some(6), None, None)), (7,List(None, Some(B), Some(4.0))))
```

If you want both an arbitrary number of lists and well-typed results, that's probably beyond the scope of a stackoverflow answer but could probably be accomplished with [shapeless.](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless)

Comment: That works with *two* lists of *pairs*. These are two additional restrictions. I understood that OP wanted arbitrary number of lists with tuples of varying arity.

Comment: Hmm, yeah I guess your interpretation could be right. But it seems like going from this to more lists or tuples of higher arity shouldn't be too hard. Full outer joining N lists can be done by full outer joining two lists N-1 times (and doing a bunch of unpacking nested tuples). Doing it in a more general way without losing type info probably requires shapeless and is significantly harder.

Comment: For some reason I have the impression that people who care about outer joins usually don't care about Shapeless at all. For example, Apache Spark is completely fine with throwing all the type information out of the window. Doing this for `List[List[Any]]` shouldn't be too hard, but then again: I don't see how this can be done without some kind of external schema that doesn't have to be inferred from the content of tuples.

Comment: To be fair to spark, the lower-level RDD api does do typed joins; the method signature is essentially identical to what I gave in this answer. But yeah, the dataset/sql api is woefully untyped.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it using `collect` separately on both list

```
val list1Ite =  list1.collect{
  case ele if list2.filter(e=> e._1 == ele._1).size>0 => { //if list2 _1 contains ele._1
     val left = list2.find(e=> e._1 == ele._1) //find the available element
     (ele._1, ele._2, left.get._2) //perform join
  }
  case others => (others._1, others._2, None) //others add None as _3 
}
//list1Ite: List[(Int, Int, java.io.Serializable)] = List((1,2,A), (3,4,None), (5,6,None))
```

Do similar operation but exclude the elements which are already available in `list1Ite`

```
val list2Ite = list2.collect{
  case ele if list1.filter(e=> e._1 == ele._1).size==0 => (ele._1, None , ele._2)
}
//list2Ite: List[(Int, None.type, String)] = List((7,None,B))
```

Combine both `list1Ite` and `list2Ite` to `result`

```
val result = list1Ite.++(list2Ite)

result: List[(Int, Any, java.io.Serializable)] = List((1,2,A), (3,4,None), (5,6,None), (7,None,B))
```

Comment: Your solution works for 2 lists, but I need it to work for N lists